# how do capture(grep/awk/sed) substring from a string the value in shell

Tags: grep

New to scripting. I have only one line & one file. How do I capture summerfruit value (ie "mango") & pass it to another variable from the below line.

.. abc.dfe  summer.fruit=mango summer.vegetable=potato projects.blah ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `grep` supports Perl-compatible regular expressions (PCRE):

```
summerfruit=$(grep -Po 'summer\.fruit=\K[^ ]+' file)
```

The `\K` doesn't print the matched `summer.fruit=` and `[^ ]+` matches one or more non-space characters after the `=`.

without PCRE:

```
summerfruit=$(grep -o 'summer\.fruit=[^ ]*' file | grep -o '[^=]*$')
```

---

With `sed`:

```
summerfruit=$(sed 's/.*summer\.fruit=\([^ ]*\).*/\1/' file)
```

---

With `awk`:

```
summerfruit=$(awk '{
  for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)
    if ($i ~ /^summer\.fruit=/){ sub(/^[^=]*=/,"",$i); print $i; exit }
}' file)
```

Comment: Freddy Thanks. When I use this in Jenkins declarative pipeline groovy script it throws an error " WorkflowScript: 79: unexpected char: '\' @ line 79, column 46" . is that because of the PCRE unsppport?

Comment: I don't know what the problem is. Added a few more solutions to try.

Comment: Thank you very Much Freddy, this will really help me to investigate proceed further. I will update the answer once i found it.

Comment: To reveal this was part of the bigger problem I had.however I am close to the solution now. apparently the below worked for me in the Jenkins pipeline script. Thanks Freddy for you initial direction. It really helped. 

sh "grep -Po 'fruit=[^ ]+' file | cut -d'=' -f2-"

Now my question how do I capture the value in a variable to use further in the pipeline?
also I am seeing the value in Jenkins logs like below which I can manage with.

mango
mango
mango
mango
mango

Comment: after doing little more google I got the final solution used like pk = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "grep -Po 'fruit=[^ ]+' file | cut -d'=' -f2-")  & worked & i had delete the file at the end which resolve the multiple entry. it as using the same file & catching the fruit value. Learning!!